# Fixing Mailchimp Opt-In Functionality - Going from Test to Production

Tags: javascript, html, css, shared-libraries, email-validation

I am having tremendous trouble taking my test state version of my mailchimp opt-in and applying it to my website (built on the weebly platform).

**My Goal: Creating a custom Mailchimp Opt-in form on Weebly.**

**Problem: Test version (locally hosted) of opt-in utterly fails on Production version (weebly platform).**

I think one library or another is getting overridden.  Perhaps the mailchimp CDN, but not sure.

Libraries used:

- Bootstrap
- FontAwesome
- Mailchimp CDN

I am adding it to my weebly site using the code embed snippet tool.  Which is probably adding another layer of complexity to the functionality.

**Here is my opt-in form code:**

```html
<!-- FontAwesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="http://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup {
        background:#283184; 
        color: white; 
        clear:left; 
        font:19px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
        width: 800px; 
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 15px; 
        }
    .btn {
        background-color: #339bff;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .label {
        font: 28px;
    }
    .asterisk {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<!-- container Body -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup" class="container">
<form action="https://silverlinkfunding.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=459fcc96e094a6b4dbe3e69f8&amp;id=4afd1b9608" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 <h2 class="text-center"><b>Apply Now</b></h2>
 <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
 <!-- Name Row -->
 <div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6 mc-field-group">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name<span class="asterisk">*</span>
     </label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="" id="mce-FNAME" name="FNAME" aria-describedby="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name">    
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 mc-field-group">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name<span class="asterisk">*</span>
     </label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="" id="mce-LNAME" name="LNAME" aria-describedby="lastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name">    
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
    <!-- Email Row -->
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mc-field-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label for="mce-EMAIL"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Email Address<span class="asterisk">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="" id="mce-EMAIL" name="EMAIL" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="YourEmail@Domain.com">    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Phone Row -->
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mc-field-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label for="mce-MMERGE3"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> Phone  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="" name="MMERGE3"   id="mce-MMERGE3" aria-describedby="phone" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx">    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Business, City, State Row -->
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 mc-field-group">
                    <label for="mce-MMERGE4"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i> Business Name<span class="asterisk">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="" id="mce-MMERGE4" name="MMERGE4" aria-describedby="businessname" placeholder="My Businesss LLC">    
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 mc-field-group">
                    <label for="mce-MMERGE5"><i class="fas fa-city"></i> City<span class="asterisk">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="" id="mce-MMERGE5" name="MMERGE5" aria-describedby="city" placeholder="Enter City Name">  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 mc-field-group">
                    <label for="mce-MMERGE9"><i class="fas fa-map-pin"></i> State<span class="asterisk">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="" id="mce-MMERGE9" name="MMERGE9" aria-describedby="state" placeholder="">  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Phone Row -->
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 mc-field-group">
                    <label for="mce-MMERGE7">Loan Amount Requested  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="" name="MMERGE7" class="required" id="mce-MMERGE7" placeholder="$xx,xxx"> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 mc-field-group">
                    <label for="mce-MMERGE8">Cash Available For Investment  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="" name="MMERGE8" class="required" id="mce-MMERGE8" placeholder="$xx,xxx">   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
 </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_459fcc96e094a6b4dbe3e69f8_4afd1b9608" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear d-flex justify-content-center"><input type="submit" value="Apply Now" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button btn" onclick="window.open('https://www.silverlinkfunding.com/thank-you-application.html')"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[3]='MMERGE3';ftypes[3]='phone';fnames[4]='MMERGE4';ftypes[4]='text';fnames[7]='MMERGE7';ftypes[7]='text';fnames[8]='MMERGE8';ftypes[8]='text';fnames[5]='MMERGE5';ftypes[5]='text';fnames[9]='MMERGE9';ftypes[9]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

**Test State (on local machine):**

- Form validation works - stays on page onclick and alerts various form
  windows which don't meet validation.
- Form opts in successfully to mailchimp
- Form redirects to /thank-you-application page

**Production State (hosted on weebly):**

- Form validation Fails
- Form validation doesn't stop redirect to thank you page
- several fontawesome icons fail

Currently live version of the opt-in form: https://www.silverlinkfunding.com/color-me-mine.html

**My Questions:**

- Is a library getting overridden?
- Is Something on weebly overriding everything?
- Did I just code it wrong?
- Am I calling the CDN's or libraries improperly?

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your console you should be able to see four warnings like the one below:

```
[blocked] The page at https://www.silverlinkfunding.com/color-me-mine.html was not allowed to run insecure content from http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js.
```

Perhaps you could try loading those files over https to see if this solves the issue concerning MailChimp.

Comment: Worked! Added an s to the http: files and it fixed 90% of the issues.  Still have some other bugs (certain fontawesome font's not firing) and some css acting weird, but the hard stuff is fixed!  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped! Please do accept the answer if it was the solution to your problem :-)